# searching for $f(x)$ when knowing $f(2^{2x})$

Tags: number-theory

I have a function that works for powers of 2

This is only for INTEGERS

is there a way to calculate any integer x?

$$f(2^{2x})=\frac{4^x+2}3.$$

$f(x)$=?

here are the first 100 values of f(x)

1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, \ 14, 14, 16, 16, 14, 14, 16, 16, 22, 22, 24, 24, 22, 22, 24, 24, 30, \ 30, 32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 32, 22, 22, 24, 24, 22, 22, 24, 24, 30, 30, \ 32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 32, 22, 22, 24, 24, 22, 22, 24, 24, 30, 30, 32, \ 32, 30, 30, 32, 32, 22, 22, 24, 24, 22, 22, 24, 24, 30, 30, 32, 32, \ 30, 30, 32, 32, 54, 54, 56, 56, 54 is there a pattern to calculate any f(x)?

thanx

Comment: Please explain in the description of the problem that you are concerned with integer valued objects, or otherwise elaborate.

Comment: In short, _no_ - not without further information. A **function** is different than a **formula**; a function can take on whatever values it wants. The formula you give defines $f()$ at a particular subset of integer values; but $f()$ can be whatever it wants in between those values.

Comment: Can you add a graph of the function?

Answer (score 7):

$$f(2^{2x})=\frac{4^x+2}{3}=\frac{(2^2)^x+2}{3}=\frac{2^{2x}+2}{3}$$ so $$f(x)=\frac{x+2}{3}$$

Comment: the function works for integers,if I know f(1),f(4),f(16)... can i find f(10)? I believe it is a number theory problem...

Comment: I don't understand your question, $f(10)=4$. If you are asking how you would evaluate that with your original function you would need to find $x$ such that $2^{2x}=10$ so in this case $x= \log_2(10)/2$. Plugging this in you would once again obtain $f(2^{2\times \log_2(10)/2})=f(2^{\log_2(10)})=f(10)=4$.

Comment: for x=1..16 in f(x) I must get 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6 the values f(1),f(4),f(16) are ok

Comment: first 100 values 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 8, \
14, 14, 16, 16, 14, 14, 16, 16, 22, 22, 24, 24, 22, 22, 24, 24, 30, \
30, 32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 32, 22, 22, 24, 24, 22, 22, 24, 24, 30, 30, \
32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 32, 22, 22, 24, 24, 22, 22, 24, 24, 30, 30, 32, \
32, 30, 30, 32, 32, 22, 22, 24, 24, 22, 22, 24, 24, 30, 30, 32, 32, \
30, 30, 32, 32, 54, 54, 56, 56, 54  is there a pattern to calculate any f(x)?

Comment: I think the function you are describing here is different than the one asked in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $4^x=2^{2x}$, so you can simply swap them both for $x$ and get
$$
f(x)=\frac{x+2}{3}
$$
This new description is only valid for positive real $x$, and even then only if the original description was valid for any real $x$. If the original expression was only valid for integer $x$, for instance, then it would probably be better to leave it unchanged.

Comment: the function works for integers,if I know f(1),f(4),f(16)... can i find f(10)? I believe it is a number theory problem...

Answer (score 1):

In general if we have,

$$f(g(x))=h(x)$$

And if there exists an inverse to $g$. Then let $u=g(x)$. This implies $g^{-1}(u)=x$ where this notation refers to the inverse of $g$. Substituting  in we have,

$$f(u)=h(g^{-1}(u))$$

Which means,

$$f(x)=h(g^{-1}(x))$$